# localStorage remove items with specific name

Tags: javascript, local-storage

For release purpose i was setting a bool with a version number in the localStorage but didn't want to flood the users localStorage because the entries don't get removed automatically.

Comment: So your question is ? Do you want to remove the items that you've set so far ?

Comment: Not all items but the the ones containing a determined string like key = string1. I found the answer myself, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So i did this:
Traverse the localStorage array, compare the key to a string and remove this item if it matches:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                var key = localStorage.key(i);
                if (key.indexOf("string") !== -1) {
                    localStorage.removeItem(key);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to remove a `localStorage` item with name `string`.

You can simply remove the item using

```
localStorage.removeItem("string");
```

No need to loop through localStorage

Comment: The thing is, i have multiple items in the localStorage labeled with a keyword and a incrementing version number. And i wanted to find all the ones with the keyword and delete them.

Comment: @DrDreo Actually whats your question. What are you trying to achieve ?